# How actually does GROUP BY + SUM + OVER + ORDER BY work?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions, database-partitioning

I understand that this query will produce numbers and cumulative tallies:

```sql
SELECT number
     , SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY number) cumulative_number
  FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) inside
 GROUP BY number
```

Result:

| number | cumulative_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 6 |

---

And I sort of get how this function works. There are partitions constructed by my `GROUP BY` clause "`GROUP BY number`". My partitions are `number` = 1, `number` = 2 and `number` = 3. And for example in the `number` = 2 case, somehow the `SUM()` function is magically accessing rows outside its partition which is somehow designated by my `window_spec` `order_clause` "`ORBER BY number`".

**But what I don't understand is how the [MySQL documentation of ORDER BY in this context](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) has anything to do with anything.**

> order_clause: An ORDER BY clause indicates how to sort rows in each partition. Partition rows that are equal according to the ORDER BY clause are considered peers. If ORDER BY is omitted, partition rows are unordered, with no processing order implied, and all partition rows are peers.

A partition is a set. Sets are unsorted according to first-grade math. So sorting something inside a partition is already tripping my BS detector. Even if you tell me that sets are ordered, the sum function I learned in first grade certainly does not care what order its operands are sorted.

---

Extending this misunderstanding to another concrete example:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(number, -1) tens
     , SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY number) cumulative_number
  FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) inside
 GROUP BY tens
```

Assuming that MySQL documentation means *something useful* and is not just wrong words. Let's consider how `ORDER BY` applies here by `number`s. The 11 does not equal the 12, they are different and so an `ORDER BY` differentiates them. They are both in the `tens` = 10 partition. So magically somehow the `SUM()` function needs to pick the sum of 3 or the sum of 4 expression result from the 11 or 12 row from inside the `tens` = 10 partition.

**How does it pick the result it does (spoiler: it picks the sum of 4)?**

And also...

**What fundamental wisdom in the MySQL documentation am I failing to appreciate, or how is that documentation deficient?**

Comment: The second query is malformed and doesn't run. You cannot `ORDER BY number`, but you could `ORDER BY ROUND(number, -1)`.

Answer (score 0):

In the query:

```
SELECT number,
  SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY number) cumulative_number
FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) inside
GROUP BY number
```

Since you didn't use a `PARTITION BY` clause in the window function, the window function has a single partition. That is, it considers all the resulting rows of the aggregation as a single partition.

The aggregation returns three rows:

- `1`
- `2`
- `3`

Then, the window function `SUM()` computes the running sum of it (1, 3, 6). There's no magic in it.

Comment: I'm using the sum function. Not the running_sum function. The sum function is not defined as having any hysteresis, so that's magic.

Comment: If you append an `OVER(ORDER BY ...)` clause to a `SUM()` function, that's a "running sum".

Answer (score 0):

Window functions allow to show individual values and aggregate values at same time. Maybe it is the `GROUP BY number` that is confusing you.

The query:

```
SELECT number
     , SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY number) cumulative_number
  FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) inside
 GROUP BY number
```

Produces the same result as the query:

```
SELECT number
     , SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY number) cumulative_number
  FROM (SELECT 1 number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) inside
```

The wndow function treats all rows as one partition (unless you use `PARTITION BY`). It does aggregation for each row. The `SUM(number) OVER (ORDER BY number)` applies to all rows. As the query has only one normal column and a window function, the `GROUP BY` will do nothing.

Comment: Got it, I see how the GROUP BY is not doing anything. But what I don't see why ORDER BY is having an effect. The RANK function cares what order its arguments come in. But the SUM function does not care what order its arguments are in, so this is what looks like magic.

Comment: As The Impaler said, no magic in it. The window function works row by row when you do not have user PARTITION BY. For the first row the partition contains (1), in second row it contains (1,2) and in the third row it contains (1,2,3). You can try `ORDER BY number desc` and see the effect it has.